# Javascript: How to add event via button to Outlook Calendar

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, outlook

I currently have a working vbscript implementation written:

```
<code>
<script language="VBScript">
    <!--
    sub MakeAppointment(MySubject, MyLocation, MyStart, MyEnd, MyMessage)
    Dim objOutlook
    Dim itmCalendar
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set itmCalendar = objOutlook.CreateItem(1)

    itmCalendar.Subject = MySubject
    itmCalendar.Location = MyLocation
    itmCalendar.Start = MyStart
    itmCalendar.End = MyEnd
    itmCalendar.Body = MyMessage

    itmCalendar.Save

    Msgbox "Appointment has been added to your Outlook Calendar!", 0, MyStart

    Set itmCalendar = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    end sub
    -->
</script>
<script language="VBScript">
    <!-- 
    Sub btnAdd_onclick()
    MySubject="All your base are belong to us" 
    MyLocation="Japan"
    MyStart="05/19/2011 07:00"
    MyEnd="05/19/2011 08:00"
    MyMessage = "This is a English review course." & vbcrlf
    MyMessage = MyMessage & "" & vbcrlf
    MyMessage = MyMessage & "" & vbcrlf
    MyMessage = MyMessage & "" & vbcrlf
    MakeAppointment MySubject, MyLocation, MyStart, MyEnd, MyMessage
    End Sub
    -->
</script>
</code>
```

I am in need of some help on how to re-write this for Javascript as another SharePoint site I am writing for is using Javascript as its default validation script language. Is it even possible? Any links to possible resources on getting this accomplished?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer didn't help me. So I will post what I found helpful as of December 2015.

```
http://calendar.live.com/calendar/calendar.aspx?rru=addevent
```

Parameters:

**dtstart**  (*yyyymmddThhmmss*)

> Required. Specifies the event's start date and time. For example,
>   20110101T120000 represents January 1, 2011, at noon. Note that the
>   portion specifying the event time (T120000) is optional.

**dtend** (*yyyymmddThhmmss*)

> Required. Specifies the event's end date and time. For example,
>   20110101T120000 represents January 1, 2011, at noon. Note that the
>   portion specifying the event time (T120000) is optional.

**summary** (*Escaped string*)

> Optional. Specifies the event's title.

**location** (*Escaped string*)

> Optional. Specifies the event’s location text.

```html
<a href="http://calendar.live.com/calendar/calendar.aspx?rru=addevent&dtstart=2015-12-07T20:00:00+00:00&dtend=2015-12-07T22:00:00+00:00&summary=Weekly Planning&location=BigCoHQ">Add to Outlook</a>
```

Source: [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846807.aspx#single)

Comment: Note that dtstart and dtend needs to be UTC time, i.e. prefixed with a "Z", or the event will be deemed to be floating, meaning that it'll be at the same time of day across timezones. Correct format: 20160513T130000Z. Incorrect format: 20160513T130000.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by populating the event information directly to the outlook link, so it'll redirect you to a modal that you can verify if the event information is correct before saving it to your calendar.

```html
<a href="https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/calendar/view/Month&rru=addevent&startdt=20200213T000000Z&enddt=20200214T000000Z&subject=Test+Event&location=Dublin">Add to Outlook Calendar</a>
```

The following link example contains the parameters in case you want to populate information from an object

[https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/calendar/view/Month&rru=addevent&startdt=${eventStart}&enddt=${eventEnd}&subject=${eventName}&location=${eventLocation}&body=${eventDescription}](https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/calendar/view/Month&rru=addevent&startdt=$%7BeventStart%7D&enddt=$%7BeventEnd%7D&subject=$%7BeventName%7D&location=$%7BeventLocation%7D&body=$%7BeventDescription%7D)

Comment: This worked nicely for me, thanks for you answer!
I'd like to know about all query string parameters available, do you have any link reference?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. Here is the one which is working as of November 2022:

```
https://outlook.live.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose?allday=false&body=This%20is%20event%20description&enddt=2022-11-29T15%3A15%3A00%2B00%3A00&path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addevent&startdt=2022-11-29T14%3A45%3A00%2B00%3A00&subject=TestEvent
```

You can generate it via this link as well: https://www.labnol.org/calendar/

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a more readable and usable code I separated the fields for the calendar. The date needs an ISO format like `'2023-08-07T01:00:00.000Z'`, and everything else is just a string.

If you only want the final href, you can use the link provided in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74615433/9801177) https://www.labnol.org/calendar/, which will generate the final url you can use.

```js
const event = {
  title: "Event title",
  description: "This is the description",
  startTime: new Date("Aug 06 2023 19:00:00"),
  endTime: new Date("Aug 06 2023 22:00:00"),
  address: "123 main street",
}

let href = encodeURI(
  [
    "https://outlook.live.com/calendar/0/action/compose",
    "?allday=false",
    "&body=" + event.description,
    "&enddt=" + event.endTime.toISOString(),
    "&location=" + event.address,
    "&path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose",
    "&rru=addevent",
    "&startdt=" + event.startTime.toISOString(),
    "&subject=" + event.title,
  ].join("")
);
```

After this you can just set the href in your anchor tag or whatever element you want to use like `document.querySelector("#outlook-link").href = href"`